# Adding supertest to Aurelia causes error when building vendor bundle

Tags: node.js, aurelia, supertest, build-error

I have a current project using aurelia.

I add the supertest library using npm.

`npm install supertest --save-dev`

Now add package to aurelia.json file

`{
    "name": "supertest",
    "path": "../node_modules/supertest"
}`

Now run aurelia build

`au run`

produces following error:

`Tracing supertest...
error /Users/xxxxxxx/node_modules/supertest.js
Writing app-bundle.js...`

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some libs require you to also define `"main" : "index.js"` (or whatever the entry module file is) in package definition. Take a look in [Aurelia Hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6) and also scroll down for info on legacy and very stubborn legacy libs. However, the `supertest` lib doesn't sound like a good candidate for adding to the bundle. If you are only going to consume it from tests, then no point in bundling it with the app - it should be dev dependency and not runtime one.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic Thanks for the feedback. I have tried every parameter without any success. I believe the problem is with the Aurelia CLI bundler as pointed out below by dan93 I have changed the way I am loading the package supertest in my test scripts so that I do not have to include it in the Aurelia vendor bundle and that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the aurelia-skeleton-navigation setup instead which uses Gulp and JSPM -> https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation. This will provide you more on control on your project.

Aurelia CLI is still on alpha, quoting from https://github.com/aurelia/cli:

> Note: The CLI is currently in Alpha and as such may not be suitable for use on all projects yet. In particular, projects that need to make use of extensive 3rd party libraries or Aurelia plugins may not yet work or may require extensive custom configuration or workarounds. We are in the process of addressing these issues.

Emphasis on *extensive custom configuration or workarounds* lol. I myself tried the CLI initially but ended up switching to Gulp and JSPM setup instead because of the tedious importing of external libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the info and feedback. I am committed an Aurelia CLI project so switching up at this point in time is not an option. I have found a work around. I just load the package in the test initializer and side step the vender bundle. It is working so far.